# Filter a panda catagorical dataframe by column values then update its categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting on with panda catagorical dataframes.

Let's say I have **(1)**:

```
A    B     C
-------------
3    Z     M
O    X     T
4    A     B
```

I filtered the dataframe like that :   `df[ df['B'] != "X"]`
So I would get as result **(2)**:

```
A    B     C
-------------
3    Z     M
4    A     B
```

In **(1)** `df['B'].cat.categories  #would equal to ['Z', 'X', 'A']`

In **(2)** `df['B'].cat.categories  #still equal to ['Z', 'X', 'A']`

How to update the DF categories of all columns after this kind of filtering operation ?

**BONUS** : If you want to clean up the indexes after the filtering

```
df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Maybe `new_df = df[df.B !='X'].copy(); new_df.B = new_df.B.astype(str).astype('category')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's kind off brute-forcing since it will pass the series all over again, a better solution is just to remove the category using .cat.remove_unused_categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove_unused_categories` from the columns after filtering.

As piRSquared points out you can do this succinctly given every column is a categorical dtype:

```
df = df.query('B != "X"').apply(lambda s: s.cat.remove_unused_categories())
```

---

This loops over the columns after filtering.

```
print(df)
#   A  B  C
#0  3  Z  M
#1  O  X  T
#2  4  A  B

df['B'].cat.categories
#Index(['A', 'X', 'Z'], dtype='object')

df = df[ df['B'] != 'X']

# Update all category columns
for col in df.dtypes.loc[lambda x: x == 'category'].index:
    df[col] = df[col].cat.remove_unused_categories()

df['B'].cat.categories
#Index(['A', 'Z'], dtype='object')

df['C'].cat.categories
#Index(['B', 'M'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: `df.query('B != "X"').apply(lambda s: s.cat.remove_unused_categories())`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas store the categories separately and don't remove them if not used, if you want do do that you can use this attribute: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories